# jQuery - Executing another javascript file

Tags: jquery, getscript

In jQuery, how do I execute another javascript file?

I have the following files:

- folder/page.html
- folder/objects/control.js
- folder/objects/test.js

In the `page.html`, I have the following code:

```
<script src="objects/control.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

In the `control.js`, I have the following code:

```
var url = "objects/test.js";
$.getScript( url, function() {
    alert("test");
});
```

In the `test.js`, I have the following code:

```
alert("test script loaded");
```

How can I load and execute the `test.js` javascript file from the `control.js` file?

I am getting the following console error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   file:///**Path**/objects/test.js?_=1434593302488. Cross origin
>   requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome,
>   chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

I am running this locally.

Comment: Is something unclear about the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you running this project locally? If so try running it on WAMP, or MAMP, or some other local web server.

Answer (score 0):

I think your url is wrong. Try below code.

```
var url = "/objects/test.js";
$.getScript( url, function() {
    alert("test");
});
```